# Select and store data from string in python

Tags: python, string

I got the information of a txt file and store it as `lines`

```
print(lines)

['>chr12_9180206_+:chr12_118582391_+:a1;2 total_counts: 115 Seed: 4 K: 20 length: 79\n', 'TTGGTTTCGTGGTTTTGCAAAGTATTGGCCTCCACCGCTATGTCTGGCTGGTTTACGAGC\n', 'AGGACAGGCCGCTAAAGTG\n', '>chr12_9180206_+:chr12_118582391_+:a2;2 total_counts: 135 Seed: 4 K: 20 length: 80\n', 'CTAACCCCCTACTTCCCAGACAGCTGCTCGTACAGTTTGGGCACATAGTCATCCCACTCG\n', 'GCCTGGTAACACGTGCCAGC\n']
```

If you execute the code

```
for i in lines:
   print(i)
```

You get:

```
>chr12_9180206_+:chr12_118582391_+:a1;2 total_counts: 115 Seed: 4 K: 20 length: 79

TTGGTTTCGTGGTTTTGCAAAGTATTGGCCTCCACCGCTATGTCTGGCTGGTTTACGAGC

AGGACAGGCCGCTAAAGTG

>chr12_9180206_+:chr12_118582391_+:a2;2 total_counts: 135 Seed: 4 K: 20 length: 80

CTAACCCCCTACTTCCCAGACAGCTGCTCGTACAGTTTGGGCACATAGTCATCCCACTCG

GCCTGGTAACACGTGCCAGC
```

I want to store the sequences that are in caps `TTGGTTTCGTGGTTT...` as independent elements in an object so you can operate with them, so you would be able to do something like:

```
seq[1]
>>> TTGGTTTCGTGGTTTTGCAAAGTATTGGCCTCCACCGCTATGTCTGGCTGGTTTACGAGCAGGACAGGCCGCTAAAGTG
```

Comment: This looks like a FASTA file

Comment: Is uppercase the only requirement or also only letters/no spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gattaca = [x.strip() for x in lines if x.isupper()]

>>> gattaca
['TTGGTTTCGTGGTTTTGCAAAGTATTGGCCTCCACCGCTATGTCTGGCTGGTTTACGAGC',
 'AGGACAGGCCGCTAAAGTG',
 'CTAACCCCCTACTTCCCAGACAGCTGCTCGTACAGTTTGGGCACATAGTCATCCCACTCG',
 'GCCTGGTAACACGTGCCAGC']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
lines = list(map(str.strip, (filter(str.isupper, lines))))
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you use `isupper()` you can check if your string in the list is upper case. If `True`, it means it is.

```
for i in lines:
   if i.isupper():
      ## store the string
```

Answer (score 1):

To check wheter a string is caps I woult use `mySting == mySting.upper()`.

To get all caps elements you could use a list comprehension like so:

```
result = [s for s in lines if lines == lines.upper()]
```

This would still allow special characters in your string.

If you only want uppercase leters then use lines.isalpha().

```
result = [s for s in lines if lines == lines.upper() and lines.isalpha()]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex:

```
import  re

seq={}
pattern=r'^(>.*$)\n([ACGTU\n]*?)(?=^>|\Z)'
for i,m in enumerate(re.finditer(pattern, ''.join(lines), flags=re.M)):
    seq[i]=m.group(2).replace('\n','')
```

Then each FASTA seq is mapped to an integer:

```
>>> seq
{0: 'TTGGTTTCGTGGTTTTGCAAAGTATTGGCCTCCACCGCTATGTCTGGCTGGTTTACGAGCAGGACAGGCCGCTAAAGTG', 1: 'CTAACCCCCTACTTCCCAGACAGCTGCTCGTACAGTTTGGGCACATAGTCATCCCACTCGGCCTGGTAACACGTGCCAGC'}
```